# Introducing the style file or script to the WordPress template

Tags: php, wordpress

I have designed a **WordPress** theme for myself.

To introduce the `style` and script files to the `WordPress` theme, I have included this code in the `function` file so that I can introduce my `CSS` and `JS` files to the theme:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'files_assets' );

function files_assets() {
    
// Introducing CSS files
  wp_enqueue_style( 'Bootstrap-min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '4.0.0' );


// Introducing JS files
  wp_enqueue_script( 'jQuery3.4.1', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.4.1', true );

}
```

Since my template has a lot of `styling` and `scripts`, I have divided my `style` and `script` files into several sections.

Now I have **35 css** files and **26 script** files that I need to introduce to my template via the above codes, which is very difficult!

Is there a `code` that instead of introducing individual files, I can only introduce the desired `folder` and all the files in that folder will be linked to my `WordPress` template?

Or is there an easier way that I don't have to introduce **61 files** to my template one by one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using class and object. You need to create an object for all files.

For example, I have some files like test1.css,test2.css, and so on.

Try it out this way:

```
/**
 * Register styles
 */
class JSXStyle {
    /**
     * Construct function.
     *
     * @param FileName $name file name.
     */
    public function __construct( $name ) {
        $this->name = $name;
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'register_custom_style' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Function for registering custom files.
     */
    public function register_custom_style() {
        wp_enqueue_style( $this->name, get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/assets/css/{$this->name}.css", array(), '1.0.0' );
    }
}

new JSXStyle( 'test1' );
new JSXStyle( 'test2' );
new JSXStyle( 'test3' );
new JSXStyle( 'test4' );

/**
 * Register scripts
 */
class JSXScript {
    /**
     * Construct function.
     *
     * @param FileName $name file name.
     */
    public function __construct( $name ) {
        $this->name = $name;
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'register_custom_script' ) );
    }

    /**
     * Function for registering custom files.
     */
    public function register_custom_script() {
        wp_enqueue_script( $this->name, get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/assets/js/{$this->name}.js", array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
    }
}

new JSXScript( 'test1' );
new JSXScript( 'test2' );
new JSXScript( 'test3' );
new JSXScript( 'test4' );
```

Comment: Yes, I noticed this and now it works perfectly. Thank you very much for your help.